# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed error

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am trying to parse my database feed data as XML, however on the client side I am keep getting this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost:12736/Test.aspx
Line Number 7, Column 26:        

 <Publication Date>29/04/2015 09:40:53</Publication Date>
 ------------------^
```

I have tried converting the datetime parameter 'ActivateDate' into string, but I am still getting the same error on the 'publication date' node. I have also tried looking online for a solution but I am still unable to solve this.

Here is my server code for further reference:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        using (XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xml.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xml.Indentation = 4;
            xml.WriteStartDocument();
            xml.WriteStartElement("items");

            foreach (DataRow oFeedItem in dt.Rows)
            {

               // DateTime dtt = DateTime.Parse(oFeedItem["ACTIVEDATE"].ToString());

                string dat = Convert.ToString(oFeedItem["ACTIVEDATE"].ToString()); 

               // dat.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"); 
                xml.WriteStartElement("Article");
                xml.WriteElementString("title", oFeedItem["title"].ToString());
                xml.WriteStartElement("description");
                xml.WriteCData(oFeedItem["Body"].ToString());
                xml.WriteEndElement();
                xml.WriteElementString("categories", oFeedItem["categories"].ToString());
                xml.WriteElementString("Publication Date", dat);
                xml.WriteEndElement();
            }

            xml.WriteEndElement();
            xml.WriteEndDocument();
            xml.Flush();
            xml.Close();

            Response.End();

        }
```

Thank you for your suggestion and feedback.

Comment: What happens when you plug your XML into here: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: When the Xml is not well formed it means you violate one of the following rules: 
    - XML documents must have a root element
    - XML elements must have a closing tag
    - XML tags are case sensitive
    - XML elements must be properly nested
    - XML attribute values must be quoted

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML element names can't contain spaces.

[W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) declares xml tag as:

```
'<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
```

where `S` is one or more whitespace characters (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA).

So from this specification it is clearly seen that space (#x20) considered as delimiter between element name and attributes list - so name itself can't contain spaces.

Changing your element `Publication Date` name to `Publication_Date` will help to make your xml well-formed.

```
xml.WriteElementString("Publication_Date", dat);
```

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank you for your feedback.  I was unaware the cause of the the problem was so trivial.  Sorry for wasting your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Element names cannot contain spaces, so change `Publication Date` to remove the space (e.g. `PublicationDate`).

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp), naming rules for elements:

- Element names are case-sensitive
- Element names must start with a letter or underscore
- Element names cannot start with the letters xml
  (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Element names can contain letters, digits,
  hyphens, underscores, and periods
- **Element names cannot contain spaces**